# Android slide animation without ViewPager

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an Activity where I'm showing 36 spinners. There is a "Previous" and a "Next" button, clicking which will change the selection of some of the spinners.

I want to implement a sliding transition, where clicking either of the buttons will slide the page out, and slide another one in. I am new to Animation, and I don't know how to do this. Please help.

Also, I don't want to use ViewPager because, as I said, my layout has 36 spinners and initializing all of them every time would be expensive.

What I basically want is for it to look like a new page is sliding in, but actually the same layout gets "refreshed".

Can someone help me with this? Any ideas, resources or code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Actually ViewPager is recycling your views so you won't create a new layout each time you switch the page. Reade about AdapterViews. Also you can try using ViewFlipper or ViewSwitcher.

Comment: But I'm not using different pages. It's the same page. And I need data from the current page to display the next page too. How can I do that?

Comment: Looks like I don't understand what do you actually try to achieve. You can try to use Fragments then.

Comment: I have some spinners with some initial selections in my layout. When a button is clicked, I have to change some of the selections.
When I click the button (when the spinners selections change), I want an animation where the page slides out, and a new page slides in.

Comment: For me the best solution here is to use fragments.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Fragment` subclass to achieve this. Each time you press the "next" button create new `Fragment` subclass instance pass necessary arguments via `Fragment.setArguments(Bundle)` to it. Use `Fragment` lifecycle methods to create and populate you view. You can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating). After you created `Fragment` subclass instance use `FragmentManager` to add it to activity with animations like this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_enter, R.anim.fragment_exit, R.anim.fragment_pop_enter, R.anim.fragment_pop_exit);
transaction.replace(R.id.activity_main_content, new MyFragmentSubclass().addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

> fragment_enter.xml

```
<set>
    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

> fragment_exit.xml

```
<set>
    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="-100%" />
</set>
```

> fragment_pop_enter.xml

```
<set>
    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

> fragment_pop_exit.xml

```
    <set>
    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="100%" />
</set>
```